# why the reply mail is sent as attachment when I send it to outlook account using javamail?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I tried in many ways to get the reply in same thread using outlook account and javamail api but iam not able to get reply in same thread instead iam getting as attachment.
I tried to copy whole content and save in current message even then iam getting as attachment, also tried to change the content disposition as inline still it didn't work
you can find the code below which i had tried.

```
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties,null); 
    store = emailSession.getStore("imaps");     
    store.connect(host,mailbox_username, mailbox_password); 
    folder = store.getFolder("Inbox");
    folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
    Message[] unreadMessages = folder.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN),false));
    if(unreadMessages.size()>0)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < unreadMessages.length; i++) 
        {
            log.info("retriving message "+(i+1))
            Message message = unreadMessages[i]

            Address[] froms = message.getFrom();
            String senderEmailAddress =(froms[0]).getAddress();

            if(senderEmailAddress.endsWith("@gmail.com"))
            {
                subject = message.getSubject()
                log.info(message.getSubject())

            }
            else
            {   //reply to same mail here we need to reply to the message
                Message message2 = new MimeMessage(emailSession);  
                message2= (MimeMessage) message.reply(false);
                message2.setSubject("RE: " + message.getSubject());  
                //message2.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));  
                message2.setReplyTo(message.getReplyTo());
                message2.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(senderEmailAddress));                        
                BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();  
                content = "some reply message"
                //multipart.addBodyPart(content);
                messageBodyPart.setText(content);                        
                Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");  
                multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);  
                messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();                   
                //messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(message.getDataHandler());  
                //bodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(ds));
                //messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpeg; name=image.jpg");
                //messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<image>");
                //messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline");
                //messageBodyPart.addBodyPart(bodyPart);
                //msg.setContent(content);
                messageBodyPart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.INLINE);
                messageBodyPart.setContent(message, "message/rfc822");
                messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(message.getDataHandler());  
                // Add part to multi part  
                multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);  
                // Associate multi-part with message  
                message2.setContent(multipart);  
                Transport t = emailSession.getTransport("smtp");
                try {
                 t.connect(mailbox_username, mailbox_password);
                    t.sendMessage(message2, message2.getAllRecipients());
                } finally {
                   t.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please focus your question on one topic. (See [help])

Comment: changed the question to particular subject please help with some explination.

Answer (score 1):

"inline" vs. "attachment" is just advice for the mail reader.  Many ignore the device, or aren't capable of displaying all content types inline.

If you want the text of the original message to appear in the body of the reply message (e.g., indented with ">"), you need to extract the original text and reformat it appropriately, adding it to the text of the reply, then set that new String as the content of the reply message.

Comment: my problem here is , I am having html table as the content of my mail. When i do this                   
text_data =  (String)message.getContent()        
println Jsoup.parse(text_data).text();                                                                      
I am getting only text of mail. But i need the whole content of the mail in same format.

Comment: The Jsoup text() method is defined to only return the plain text content.  If you want the original html content, don't use Jsoup, just use text_data.  If that's not what you want, you need to explain more clearly what you want, perhaps with an example.